# Map tooltips in the wrong location

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to include tooltips on a map I'm making in D3, imitating this code:
http://bl.ocks.org/lhoworko/7753a11efc189a936371

And here is the map I'm working on:
https://pantherfile.uwm.edu/schro333/public/2016_electoral_map/

As you can see here, I have tooltips working, and they display the correct name when the user hovers over a state, but the position relative to the cursor is really off. I'm not sure why this is.

Relevant code:

```
        svgContainer.selectAll("pathCodes")
            .data(json.features)
            .enter()
            .append("path")
            .attr("id",
                function(d){
                    var stateNameId = d.properties.name.toString();
                    stateNameId = stateNameId.replace(/\s+/g, '');
                    return stateNameId;
            }) // this function returns the name of the state with spaces stripped and assigns it to individual polygon as id
            .attr("d", pathCodes)
            .attr("stroke", "black") // state outline color
            .attr("stroke-width", "1") // state outline width
            .attr("class", "noparty") // default to no party
            .style("fill", politicalParties[0].color) // default fill is that of no party
            /////////////
            .on('mousemove', function(d) {
                var mouse = d3.mouse(svgContainer.node());
                tooltip.classed('hidden', false)
                    .attr('style', 'left:' + (mouse[0]) +
                            'px; top:' + (mouse[1]) + 'px')
                    .html(d.properties.name);
            })
            .on('mouseout', function() {
                tooltip.classed('hidden', true);
            });
            /////////////
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the wrong position because the X/Y position you are using is based off the SVG and not the actual location of the SVG on the page.

You can use

```
var loc = document.getElementById("states-map").getBoundingClientRect();
console.log(loc.top); //add this to the top
```

to get the offset. Not sure the d3 way to do it.

Comment: That did it! Thanks very much.